# Can javascript "see" elements / script inside of a display="none" element?

Tags: javascript, dom

If I hide some of the DOM by setting an element's attribute like:  `display="none"`

Will running scripts be able to locate those elements?

Comment: You could simply test this... A million times easier than asking on SO

Comment: @Gorgamite a million? Others can find this question and not have to actually test it to know the answer. Sometimes people look for these answers on their phones when they aren't at a computer. For those people, finding this question will be a million times easier than testing it. Stack Exchange is supposed to be a knowledge base

Comment: Look, the quality of your question speaks for itself. 3 Downvotes. Typically you put what you've tried so far, your issue, and maybe an error message. This question has none of those. Try visiting https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve.

Comment: @Gorgamite I know what constitutes a good question. This was to help future googlers. If it takes 30 seconds to find this answer and 120 seconds to test it, this question is worthwhile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are still part of the document. Pretty easy to find out yourself:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

```html
<div id="foo" style="display: none">I'm hidden</div>
```